Issue with vue-test-utils and module federation
I am facing below error when I run my Test case file in vue-test-utils
ypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call') at __webpack_require__ (/Users/nipun/Desktop/core-system-web-app/dist/js/webpack:/core-system-web-app/webpack/bootstrap:19:1) at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/nipun/Desktop/core-system-web-app/dist/js/webpack:/core-system-web-app/src/Test.vue:6:1) at __webpack_require__ (/Users/nipun/Desktop/core-system-web-app/dist/js/webpack:/core-system-web-app/webpack/bootstrap:19:1) at Module.<anonymous> (/Users/nipun/Desktop/core-system-web-app/dist/js/main.js:30262:217) at __webpack_require__ (/Users/nipun/Desktop/core-system-web-app/dist/js/webpack:/core-system-web-app/webpack/bootstrap:19:1) at Module.<anonymous> (/Users/nipun/Desktop/core-system-web-app/dist/js/main.js:30196:91) at __webpack_require__ (/Users/nipun/Desktop/core-system-web-app/dist/js/webpack:/core-system-web-app/webpack/bootstrap:19:1) at Object.module.exports (/Users/nipun/Desktop/core-system-web-app/dist/js/webpack:/core-system-web-app/tests/unit/Test.spec.js:3:1) at __webpack_require__ (/Users/nipun/Desktop/core-system-web-app/dist/js/webpack:/core-system-web-app/webpack/bootstrap:19:1) at run (/Users/nipun/Desktop/core-system-web-app/dist/js/webpack:/core-system-web-app/node_modules/mochapack/lib/entry.js:3:1) at Array.forEach (<anonymous>) at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/nipun/Desktop/core-system-web-app/dist/js/webpack:/core-system-web-app/node_modules/mochapack/lib/entry.js:9:1) at __webpack_require__ (/Users/nipun/Desktop/core-system-web-app/dist/js/webpack:/core-system-web-app/webpack/bootstrap:19:1) at /Users/nipun/Desktop/core-system-web-app/dist/js/webpack:/core-system-web-app/webpack/startup:4:1 at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/nipun/Desktop/core-system-web-app/dist/js/main.js:30569:12) at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1191:14) at Object.module_1.default._extensions.<computed> [as .js] (/Users/nipun/Desktop/core-system-web-app/node_modules/mochapack/src/util/registerRequireHook.ts:106:12) at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1069:32) at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:904:12) at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1093:19) at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:108:18) at /Users/nipun/Desktop/core-system-web-app/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:436:36 at Array.forEach (<anonymous>) at Mocha.loadFiles (/Users/nipun/Desktop/core-system-web-app/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:433:14) at Mocha.run (/Users/nipun/Desktop/core-system-web-app/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:1012:10) at /Users/nipun/Desktop/core-system-web-app/node_modules/mochapack/src/runner/TestRunner.ts:128:23 at /Users/nipun/Desktop/core-system-web-app/node_modules/mochapack/src/webpack/compiler/registerReadyCallback.ts:15:7 at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/nipun/Desktop/core-system-web-app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:50:1) at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (/Users/nipun/Desktop/core-system-web-app/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:18:14) at /Users/nipun/Desktop/core-system-web-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:498:23 at Compiler.emitRecords (/Users/nipun/Desktop/core-system-web-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:919:5) at /Users/nipun/Desktop/core-system-web-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:490:11 at /Users/nipun/Desktop/core-system-web-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:885:14 at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/nipun/Desktop/core-system-web-app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:10:1) at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (/Users/nipun/Desktop/core-system-web-app/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:18:14) at /Users/nipun/Desktop/core-system-web-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:882:27 at /Users/nipun/Desktop/core-system-web-app/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2818:7 at done (/Users/nipun/Desktop/core-system-web-app/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:3522:9) at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/nipun/Desktop/core-system-web-app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1) at /Users/nipun/Desktop/core-system-web-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:736:33 at MemoryFileSystem.writeFile (/Users/nipun/Desktop/core-system-web-app/node_modules/memory-fs/lib/MemoryFileSystem.js:328:9) at doWrite (/Users/nipun/Desktop/core-system-web-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:723:30) at processMissingFile (/Users/nipun/Desktop/core-system-web-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:816:15) at /Users/nipun/Desktop/core-system-web-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:856:10 at Immediate._onImmediate (/Users/nipun/Desktop/core-system-web-app/node_modules/memory-fs/lib/MemoryFileSystem.js:282:5) at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:466:21)
Below is my Test case file
import { expect } from "chai";
import { shallowMount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import Test from "@/Test";

describe("Layout.vue", () => {
  it("renders props.msg when passed", () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(Test, {});
    expect(wrapper.text()).to.include("");
  });
});


My Test component is using a module federated component. Attaching the code of that component below
<template>
    <Test2 />
</template>

<script>
import Test2 from "core/Test2";
export default {
    components: {
        Test2,
    }
}
</script>

Core is a remote project for module federation. Can anyone help me here?
Vue config file for reference:
const ModuleFederationPlugin =
  require("webpack").container.ModuleFederationPlugin;
const { ...otherPackages } = require("./package.json").dependencies;

module.exports = {
  publicPath: "/",
  productionSourceMap: false,
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  configureWebpack: {
    output: {
      filename: '[name].[contenthash].bundle.js'
    },
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: {
        chunks: "all",
      },
    },
    plugins: [
      new ModuleFederationPlugin({
        name: "consumer",
        filename: "remoteEntry.js",
        remotes: {
          core: "coreui@http://localhost:8081/remoteEntry.js",
        },
        shared: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test' ? {
          ...otherPackages
        } : {},
      }),
    ],
  },
};


I tried many solutions from google but nothing works. I may be missing some configuration.
